# Check the cluster size of an exFAT drive on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, exfat

How do I check the cluster/allocation size of an exFAT drive on Windows?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `wmic`

```
C:\>wmic volume get driveletter,blocksize
BlockSize  DriveLetter
4096       D:
4096       C:
```

On powershell you'll have various solutions like below

```
PS C:\> (Get-Volume C).AllocationUnitSize
4096
PS C:\> (Get-WmiObject win32_volume | where { $_.driveletter -eq 'C:' }).BlockSize
4096
```

Alternatively you can also run `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo drive:` as admin to get more detailed information, or use `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo <drive> | findstr /c:"Bytes Per Cluster"` to get just the cluster size

Comment: `fsutil` only works for NTFS drives, but `wmic` worked, and wasn't as risky as my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the drive and click "format", and the pop-up window will show the current cluster size under "allocation unit size". Be careful that you don't actually format the disk though!

Comment: This is not always accurate. I formatted exFat 4096 (CMD format windows 10) and not only Format window does not present the option, it shows wrongly an 128kb size. No way