# Why is 1024 Cluster Size with blank drive being shown while querying WMIC for available drives?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, ntfs, formatting, exfat

I wanted to know cluster sizes for my flash drive (ExFAT), and I followed the useful answer here:
https://superuser.com/a/1358598/602756

Here is output of cmd: `wmic volume get driveletter,blocksize`

[image]

My drives are:

- C: > NTFS Windows primary
- E: > NTFS Storage
- F: > NTFS Storage
- G: > ExFAT USB Drive 32GB
- D: > DVD R/W

I wish to know why is there blank entry for 1024 block size? Is it related to G: ExFAT USB Flash Drive?

Comment: Please do not post terminal output as screenshot. Just copy and paste it as text formatted as code.

Comment: You can simply modify the command to `wmic volume get driveletter,blocksize,capacity,filesystem` to see that it is a FAT32 partition of ~100MB without drive letter (-> UEFI boot partition).

Comment: Thanks @Robert this is correct. 100MB EFI partition, FAT32 with 1KB block size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that this volume is not mounted and thus has no drive letter assigned. In your case it is probably the EFI boot partition of your C: drive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I searched, there is no supporting information I can find, Its a logical answer.